# Flutter Firebase Auth How To Get User Current Password?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm making a password change page. The user will need to enter their current password to go to the password change section. But I don't know how to get current password. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This action is one of the sensitive actions that requires to re-authenticate the user before proceeding. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user).

Now you should ask user to re-authenticate again, if you used any provider you can get the credential from Firebase and pass to `reauthenticateWithCredential` function. But in your case that used `password` provider, meaning using `email` and `password` to sign up users, you should show a screen to users and ask them to enter their `email` and `password` again and then use that information and re-authenticate them.

#### Simple example:

Let's say we showed a screen to user and got their email and password from them and then we can use this information to re-authenticate user. If you're asking what if user logged in with `emailA` and enter `EmailB` to re-authenticate? The answer is that Firebase will throw an Exception(`user-mismatch`), so you can ask user to enter the email that they are currently logged in with.

```dart
Future<void> reauthenticateWithCredential(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    // Handle exceptions
  }
}
```

And to get credentials from other providers like `google`, is similar to log in process, you use the same code, and then get the credential and pass it to `reauthenticateWithCredential` function to re-authenticate user again.

Now you're ready to do any sensitive actions, you can delete user account or let them request for changing their password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the password you can try this [Reset Password | Firebase Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkQJQt_pQho)

Not sure you can access user's password because when you look at users in Firebase you can't see password champ.

Doing this you'll have all user's data available:

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
String userName = user!.providerData.first.displayName.toString(); // Display user's name
String userPhoto = user!.providerData.first.photoURL.toString(); // Display user's photo
```

`user.providerData.first` you'll have access user's informations but the password seems to not be available